# Scala package throws java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: scala

Our java application has dependencies on Spark, which is written in Scala. Build tool is Maven, and am running from within Eclipse. The JDK_HOME used to compile the application on the command line using Maven, and the JRE used to run within Eclipse, are both `1.7.0_15`.

The Maven POM contains the following:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
   ...
   <configuration>
      <scalaVersion>1.10.5</scalaVersion>
         <args>
            <arg>-target:jvm-1.7</arg>
         </args>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I understand that Spark is built using Scala 2.10

The maven dependencies include the following:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
   <artifactId>elasticsearch-hadoop</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.0.Beta4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
   <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.0.Beta4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
   <artifactId>scala-xml</artifactId>
   <version>2.11.0-M4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.scala-lang.modules</groupId>
   <artifactId>scala-parser-combinators_2.12.0-M2</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.4</version>
   </dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency
```

>

At runtime, the folowing exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: scala/util/parsing/combinator/PackratParsers : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

I cannot find a 2.10.* version of the `scala-parser-combinators` jar.

Can anyone assist with the solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `scala-parser-combinators_2.12.0-M2` module is part of the Scala 2.12 distribution.

2.12 is targeted for Java 8 - bytecode major version 52, hence the error.

Your best bet is to either **use an older Spark distribution or switch to Java 8** (Java 7 is at End-Of-Life since April 2015).

**EDIT (addressing question edit):** you cannot find an older version of the `scala-parser-combinators` library, because it was isolated to a stand-alone module at some point after 2.10. You can attempt to simply [exclude this dependency in your POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#Dependency_Exclusions), but there's no guarantee your chosen Spark version will be compatible with this older library version.